# Most generic mobile User-Agent header string

Tags: perl, http, http-headers, www-mechanize

I use `LWP::UserAgent` to access the web site. The site offers **almost** the same info in auto-selected layouts for pc (default?) and mobile.  Some informations are easier to get in non default layout.

Which User-Agent **most generic** strings are recommended to identify web client as mobile or pc device?
 LWP::UserAgent : `$ua->agent('…');`

P.S. So far for tests I use full string of randomly selected mobile device.  It works but I would like to set proper "style-guide" - set and forget **for LONG**.  I would like to avoid requirement for fixes every few years.

Comment: I would pick a single device that is already a couple of years old and enjoyed a large market share. How do you like that idea?

Comment: I would like something better **but** it seems to be a pretty good fallback solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my specific case `Mozilla/5.0 (Mobile)` delivers wanted results.
IMHO it is worth to try in other cases.

```
$ua->agent('Mozilla/5.0 (Mobile)');
```

I have tried it based on suggestion in
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent

> Firefox UA string
>
> […] The UA string of Firefox itself is broken down into four components:
>
> Mozilla/5.0 (platform; rv:geckoversion) Gecko/geckotrail Firefox/firefoxversion
>
> - **Mozilla/5.0** is the general token that says the browser is Mozilla compatible, and is common to almost every browser today.
> - **platform** describes the native platform the browser is running on (e.g. Windows, Mac, Linux or Android), and whether or not it's a mobile phone. Firefox OS phones simply say "Mobile"; the web is the platform.
>   […]